# How to read content from two files and merge into a 3rd file in bash shell

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, pattern-matching

How do you read/process 2 files in sync with each other in bash?

I have 2 text files which have the same number of lines/items in them.
One file is

```
a
b
c
```

The other file is

```
1
2
3
```

How do I loop through these files in sync so that `a` is associated with `1`, b->2, c->3?

I thought that I could read in the files as an array and then process them with an index but it seems like my syntax/logic is incorrect.

So doing `f1=$(cat file1)` makes `f1 = a b c`.  I thought doing `f1=($(cat file1))` would make it into an array but it makes `f1=a` and thus no array for me to process.

In case anyone was wondering what my messed up code is:

```
hostnames=($(cat $host_file))  
# trying to read in as an array, which apparently is incorrect
roles=($(cat $role_file))

for i in {0..3}
do
   echo ${hostnames[$i]}   
   # wanted to iterate through each element in the file/array
   # but there is only one object instead of N objects
   echo ${roles[$i]}
done
```

Comment: To populate an array with the contents of a file I would set the `$IFS` to `\n` and use the command `array=($(<file))` and then use the command `for ((n=0;n<${#array[@]};n++));do echo "${array[n]}";done` to process the array(s).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `paste` ([invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/paste-invocation.html)) to combine the files, then process one line of the combined file at a time:

```
paste file1 file2 |
while read -r first second
do
  echo $first
  echo $second
done
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use **[file descriptors](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors)**:

```
while read -r var_from_file1 && read -r var_from_file2 <&3; do 
    echo "$var_from_file1 ---> $var_from_file2"
done <file1 3<file2
```

#### Output:

```
a ---> 1
b ---> 2
c ---> 3
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer! `+1`.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

- with `file1`  in front:

  ```
  sed -r 's#(.*)#s/(.*)/\1 \\1/;$!n#' file1|sed -rf - file2
  ```

  or
- with `file2`  in front:

  ```
  sed -r 's#(.*)#s/(.*)/\\1 \1/;$!n#' file2|sed -rf - file1
  ```

---

Both leads to the same output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
```

Comment: Let's hope there are no slashes in the input. :-) Have a look at `paste file1 file2`, though.

Comment: @chirlu you are right, if slashes the Regex must be changed (slightly) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your way:

```
host_file=host1
role_file=role1

hostnames=(  $(cat $host_file) )  
roles=( $(cat $role_file)  )
(( cnt = ${#hostnames[@]}  -1 ))
echo "cnt is $cnt"
for (( i=0;i<=$cnt;i++))
do
  echo "${hostnames[$i]} ->    ${roles[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

two examples with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{print $0, NR}' file1
```

and - much better :-)

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next};{print a[FNR], $0}' file1 file2
```

..output is always:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Answer (score 2):

A concise and flexible solution to this problem is the core-util `pr`:

```
# space separated
$ pr -mts' ' file1 file2
a 1
b 2
c 3

# -> separated
$ pr -mts' -> ' file1 file2
a -> 1
b -> 2
c -> 3
```

See `man pr` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash:

```
IFS=$'\n'
hostnames=( $( <hostnames.txt ) )
roles=( $( <roles.txt ) )

for idx in ${!hostnames[@]}; do    # loop over array indices
  echo -e "${hostnames[idx]} ${roles[idx]}"
done
```

or after gniourf_gniourf's comment

```
mapfile -t hostnames < hostnames.txt
mapfile -t roles < roles.txt

for idx in ${!hostnames[@]}; do              # loop over array indices
  echo -e "'${hostnames[idx]}' '${roles[idx]}'"
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the fields in your arrays will not contain the lines in the file, but the words! You'd better use `mapfile` thus: `mapfile -t hostnames < hostnames.txt` and it's also much more efficient!

Comment: time(1) shows no significant difference when using 30000 line files. The switch -t removes trailing newlines. For me the array contents are equal in both versions. Do I overlook something?

Comment: it does on my system which is probably older and slower than yours. Also, `$(...)` runs a subshell whereas `mapfile` doesn't. Also, `a=( $( < file ) )` will create an array the fields of which are the words of the file, not its lines.

Comment: Thank you. The word issue can be fixed by setting IFS. Choosing mapfile can be left to the reader.